# Unittesting Angular 7 Component with @Input Observable var and subscribing to this var in ngOnInit method

Tags: angular

I am figuring out how to tackle a problem which I encountered in my unittest for an Angular Component.

I got this error:

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'

because my component (MyComponent) implements an ngOnInit method which wants to subscribe to an Input variable declared as '@Input foo: Observable;' in my component. 
On construction of my component Through TestBed, its constructor() is called and ngOnInit() subsequently. But, I am struggling where/whgen to initialize myComponent.foo = boundVarFromHostComponent;., so that by the time ngOnInit method is called myComponent.foo has a value and ngOnInit can subscribe to.

Unfortunately this approach is not possible. Assigning the component's input before construction is impossible. After constructor but before the ngOnInit call is also impossible.
I thought of initializing the Input variable to some value such as of(null) or of({...}) so that subscribing will succeed in ngOnInit (but I find this to be more a hack than a proper solution because you need to think about the functional meaning of this initialization with respect to implementation).
Unfortunately the angular site is not addressing this scenario.

Comment: *After constructor but before the ngOnInit call is also impossible*. Why would it be impossible? Just do that. 1. construct the component. 2. Bind the inputs. 3. call detectChanges. Or use host component in your test, that uses the component under test in its template and effectively binds the inputs using the template.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your input. I understand what you mean. But, as soon as the instance is created (through the TestBed/fixture) the life cycle hooks are called OnChange and OnInit which means in my case that ngOnInit. I am not able to set the component's input variable name (@Input).

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Here's a minimal complete example showing it: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/81c9a6889c615c40fd46560cf2ba1bec

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the example. I have just studied the code of the link that you sent. This is a slightly different scenario than my situation. If I slightly adapt the code that you have pointed me to, I can make my point. Change the line @Input() name: string; --> @Input() name: Observable<string>; and change the line in ngOnInit() from this.nameCopy = this.name.toUpperCase(); --> this.name.subscribe(n => this.nameCopy = d);  Now you will see that you won't be able to write a unit test which will work. Because upon creation of your component under test an error will we thrown.

Comment: After having searched for a solution to my problem as described in my posting I decided not to use TestBed for this specific scenario (Observable component input where subscribing is made in the ngOnInit method.). As I don't have control on the lifecycle hooks, I am choosing for creating manually (new) the component and provide myself its dependencies.